# Which one is best in Laravel eloquent ? Relationship or Query builders leftjoin / join queries?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

We are develop job portal website using Laravel Framework and MySQL here by the handle huge number of records( 1 million ). Already done in development now we can start the optimization process Laravel Model Query builder like below sample. 
`Model::join(contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')` convert to eloquent relationships like `belongsTo()` and `hasOne()` and `hasMany()`.

Answer (score 2):

Each one come with his advantages and disadvantages

## Eloquent

Eloquent ORM is shipped with Laravel to help interact with the database using Active Record implementation.
It represents the data as object-based, therefore it lets code accessing object instead of database table. It also provides caching and help reducing code and gives it a better clarity. But it is slower and sometimes haves limitations when writing complex queries.

## Query Builder

> Laravel's database Query Builder provides fluent interface to create and run database queries.
> Query Builder represents the database queries in PHP code, where one simply chain methods instead of writing SQL.

Query Builder is mostly appreciated because it performed most of the database operations.

## Reference

This document gives a vary details information concerning your question.
[Difference between Eloquent ORM and Query Builder](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1014983/FULLTEXT02)

Comment: Thanks for your response.